# Linebreak a string in Python sourcecode

Tags: python, line-breaks

I have

```
return "Cargo(location=%s, cargocapacity=%s, cargo=%s, name=%s, mast_count=%s)" \
        % (
            self.location,
            self.cargocapacity,
            self.cargo,
            self.name,
            self.mast_count)
```

so the first line is too long. How can i break the Line?
If i do

```
return "Cargo(location=%s, cargocapacity=%s, cargo=%s, \
       name=%s, mast_count=%s)" \
        % (
            self.location,
            self.cargocapacity,
            self.cargo,
            self.name,
            self.mast_count)
```

and print the returned string i get a lot of withespace.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe join the string with single arguments? But this will add a lot more lines of code.

Comment: consider using templating.  `template = "Cargo(location={location}, cargocapacity={cargocapacity}, cargo={cargo}, name={name}, mast_count={mast_count})"; return template.format(self)`

Comment: Note also that you probably want the `repr`, rather than `str`, forms of the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Putting strings together `"like " "this"` will join them into one, `"like this"`.  It can be used across lines.

```
return ("Cargo(location=%s, cargocapacity=%s, cargo=%s, "
        "name=%s, mast_count=%s)") % (
        self.location,
        self.cargocapacity,
        self.cargo,
        self.name,
        self.mast_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split up a string between parentheses and have Python automatically join them at compilation time:

```
return (
    "Cargo(location=%s, cargocapacity=%s, cargo=%s, "
    "name=%s, mast_count=%s)") % (
            self.location,
            self.cargocapacity,
            self.cargo,
            self.name,
            self.mast_count)
```

The parentheses are not really required if you use `\` before the end of the line, but with parentheses this is just a little cleaner.

Comment: [\ is discouraged in PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), because trailing whitespace invisibly breaks it.  In some cases, the resulting syntax is actually legal, so you get entirely wrong behavior with no obvious reason why.

Comment: @Kevin: if you have a long `with` statement, the only option to break it across multiple lines is to use backslashes. But you are right, PEP 8 discourages their use, for good reasons.

Comment: Sure, but I'd prefer to use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) there anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: which is not available in Python 2..

Comment: Lots of stuff isn't in Python 2.  That's why I prefer Python 3.

Comment: @Kevin: sure, if you have the choice; whenever I can I make that same choice. But loads of developers cannot yet make that switch. If you are targeting Google App Engine you also don't get to choose, etc.

Comment: contextlib.ExitStack has a backport -> http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @wim: sure, but a strategically-placed backslash on a wide `with` line is fine; installing a backport is overkill there.

Comment: I agree, just an fyi for any future readers